# NodeJS Firestore Authentication - Permission Denied

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a client-side script that allows someone to login to their Google Account and then access a Firestore database once they are authenticated. Everything works except for some reason after signing in using firebase.auth it isn't passing this data to firebase.firestore to say they are authenticated.

Here is the script that I am using, the only part that is failing is when I am trying to add to a Firestore collection.

```
const firebase = require ("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/firestore");

const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const util = require('util')

var config = {
    **HIDDEN**
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const SCOPES = ['email','profile'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Gmail API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listLabels);
});

function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

function listLabels(auth) {
    var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(auth.credentials.id_token);
    firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        var email = error.email;
        var credential = error.credential;

        console.log(errorCode);
        console.log(errorMessage);
    });

    var firestore = firebase.firestore();
    firestore.settings({
        timestampsInSnapshots: true
    });

    firestore.collection("users").add({
        test: "Hello"
    });

    firebase.auth().signOut();
}
```

And below is my rules for the database, if I change it to just `if true;` it works perfectly fine. But I want to make sure only an authenticated user can access that database.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential returns a promise, and you aren't waiting for it to finish before accessing the data on Firestore, so that is probably what is causing the issues. I believe this might work:

```
function listLabels(auth) {
    var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(auth.credentials.id_token);
    firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
        .then(user => {    
            var firestore = firebase.firestore();
            firestore.settings({
                timestampsInSnapshots: true
            });

            firestore.collection("users").add({
                test: "Hello"
            });

            firebase.auth().signOut();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            var email = error.email;
            var credential = error.credential;

            console.log(errorCode);
            console.log(errorMessage);
        });
}
```

Comment: Ugh, I am such an idiot. All of the examples I could find just had the authentication part and how to sign in, none included the firestore aspect. This worked.